# dialog menu to disply files and select one of them

Tags: bash, menu, dialog

Please advise me on how I can do the following with the dialog utility:

I want to display all the files under `/home` directory in menu, and select only one of them. Then the script will print the full path of the selected file.

I have created the following script:

*this script only displays the files in the dialog box menu*

```
    #!/bin/bash

    dialog --title "List file of directory /home" --msgbox "$(ls /home )" 100 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code & copy/paste not really available on the stack exchange android app.

CHOICE='dialog --title "List " --radiolist "$(ls /home)" 100 100'

echo "/home/$CHOICE"

Note: i have used ' for back-tick my keyboard has no back-tick.

Comment: NOT WORK , Not get the dialog box

Comment: Yeah your right, i can only think otf cheesey solutions which'll give functionality. What is the point of dialog at best you can detect button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 8 year old post, but it's top of my google search. I tried hard to get this working but Dialog gives me errors when using ls. So I asked chatgpt and it came back with some alternatives that worked. So I modified it for my own use and it works. So for anyone who wants to see another way to do it:

```
files=() #blank the variable so its empty for next use
# Loop folder, add files to array
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    files+=("$file" "")
done < <(find "/home" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.sh" -print0)
# or for all files: done < <(find "/home" -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0)
# Check it has at least 1 file to show (otherwise dialog errors)
if [ ${#files[@]} -eq 0 ]; then
    clear
    echo "No .sh files found in $directory"
else
    file=$(dialog --stdout --title "Select a file" --cancel-label "Back" --menu "Choose a file:" 0 0 0 "${files[@]}")
    clear
    echo "Selected file: $file"
fi
```

Comment: I don't know why this works, but I think at a guess it's the files array. Notice how it has 2 parts, "filename" "empty". Maybe for some reason it doesn't like it when it's not a 2 part array on each item?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly change --msgbox to say --radiolist. Enclose the whole of the dialog command in back-ticks and precede the whole lot CHOICE=.
It'll now read

CHOICE='dialog...

Next line reads
echo "$$HOME/$CHOICE"

Only type one $ before HOME, i either have no dollar signs or this.

Comment: can you please reedit your answer inside my code , not clearly how to integrate your solution in my code?